# Is the question view counter actually accurate?

Tags: discussion

This is, potentially, a meta-meta question, but:

Is the view counter actually correct? For this question about [router direction](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1056/why-does-direction-matter-when-using-an-electric-router) as of the [time of my noticing](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1056/why-does-direction-matter-when-using-an-electric-router#comment1330_1056), there were 3 views noted and 4 answers from 4 different people!

How does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. It was accurate at the time is was calculated but it could be higher by the time you view it. I am pretty sure this has to do with caching. I will look up the meta question about this.

In the short term [this site](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) has the answer.

[**Meta about how view calculation works**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated)

I think the answer you are looking for is there..... and yes it's caching.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you for sharing that link twice. I got a good chuckle both times.

Comment: @FreeMan I didnt realize there was a meta about this at first. The comment stood alone but it belongs in the answer. That is why I wrote [this site] as it is more likely people will look at it.